# How to read Ajax XML response from a specific tag

Tags: jquery

I recieve the following XML resonse from a ajax call

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <books>
      <sub>MATHS</sub>
   </books>
   <books>
      <sub>Chemistry</sub>
   </books>
</root>
```

My requirement is that , i always want to read the second  books sub value (that is want to retrive Chemistry value)

I tried this way , but with below code i am getting MATHS (first books )

```
$(data).find("books").each(function () {
var subject = $(this).find("sub").text().trim();
   return false;
});
```

Could you please let me know how to read the second books tag's sub value ??

Comment: I don't think you need to use `each` in your situation. Just select the second element from the result of `find("books")`.Anyways, could you please give result of console.log of `$(data).find("books")` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) like

```
$(data).find("books").each(function () {
var subject = $(this).find("sub:eq(1)").text().trim();
   return false;
});
```

As an alternative, with your current XML response, you can use [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

```
$(data).find("books").each(function () {
    var subject = $(this).find("sub:not(:first)").text().trim();
       return false;
    });
```

**or**

using [:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

```
$(data).find("books").each(function () {
        var subject = $(this).find("sub:last").text().trim();
           return false;
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , the last one seems nice

Comment: @PreethiJain, in the end, I advise you to use :eq because you may sometimes get a response of length greater than 2

Comment: @PreethiJain, if the answer did not work, let me know so we can try and work it out